# Django. Why my signal function doesn't work?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-signals

I got a model named Request with a few fields in models.py. I also got signal receiver in signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Request)
def status_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    "doing smth"
```

But when I am trying to change some fields of Request model in admin interface and then press "save", receiver didnt catch any signals and my function "status_changed" doesn't run. What kind of problem it might be and how may I solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you never include the signals file anywhere.
You should include them in your models.py and or make sure that at least one of your files registers them in order to get fired at some point.
The simplest solution would be to copy all of your signals at the end of your models.py file and see what happens.